# Does SQL Server CE support synchronization of Spatial Data type?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-ce, geospatial, spatial

Does Sql Server support replication to SQL Server CE? In the documentation, SQL server CE seems to be not supporting the st_geometry type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server Compact 3.5 Service Pack 1 supports replicating geometry and geography data types.

[What's New in SQL Server Compact 3.5 and 3.5 SP1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172417.aspx)